# Date Formatting Problem in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nsdateformatter

I have a Date column in my Dataframe, when I display the dates, The Dates format are merged, and are in random format.How to put them in right format? Like in dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Please give an example of the dataframe and include snippets of your code.

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Please not that a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) could help us, helping you.

Comment: Hi :) If the answer solved your Question, consider set the answer as accepted. So others who search for a similar problem can find it.

Answer (score 1):

This is pseudo code since you did not gave us your code. It assumed that the column `date` of a dataframe `df` is correctly formatted as datetime.

You can use the vectorized datetime function `strftime()` with (see the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html)):

```
df['date'].dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

When you want to save the changes of the format, you need to assign it again to the `date` column, like this

```
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```